# how i can execute all function in code?

Tags: c#

I wrote code below to check entered data from components in a form in C#.

This code calls some function that each return a Boolean value. If check is Ok, the functions return false else they return true.

If my user has not completed any input correctly, the first code check function returns true and the other functions calls are skipped.

How do I avoid skipping the other function calls even when one returns true?

Naming conventions:

- variables starst with 'txt' are TextBox
- variables stars with 'mtxt' are MaskedTextBox
- variables stars with 'rtxt' are RichTextBox

**code:**

```
bool allIsOK = false;

allIsOK = checker.txtChecker(txtcode) ;
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.txtChecker(txtdavar); 
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.txtChecker(txtKomakHazine);
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.txtChecker(txtnevisande);
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.txtChecker(txtonvan); 
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.txtChecker(txtostadMoshaver);
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.txtChecker(txtostadRahnama);

allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.richTextBoxChecker(rtxtmaghale);
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.mtxtDateChecker(mtxtdefa);
allIsOK = allIsOK || checker.mtxtDateChecker(mtxttasvib);
```

Comment: Why do you want it to execute the later ones? You can do it by just replacing `||` with `|` if I understand the question correctly, but why?

Comment: can you please explain what it is you are really trying to do..? it appears that you re-opened / reposted the same question again after getting -7 or more negatives votes.. please clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: @Random832 That's a good answer :) As for the "why", I would assume that it is for possible side effects of `txtChecker` (e.g. for writing into the log when the input is invalid).

Comment: when execute a function if inputComponent's value is incorrect set background color of it to red. i want all of incorrect input to red.

Comment: your method `txtChecker` should really be renamed.  Right now it doesn't indicate what it *does*.  I would suggest calling it either, `isValid` or `isInvalid` depending on which it does.  (Right now I can't even tell which it does, which is part of the problem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running into short-circuiting of the expressions; if the first part of an OR (||) is true, evaluation of the second part isn't necessary. There's a similar rule for AND (&&), if the first part is false, the second part isn't evaluated. This is by design and is a very useful characteristic of the language.

The simplest change to your code to ensure all your checks are evaluated would be to swap the order of the tests, putting the check on the left of the `||` operator.

```
allIsOK = checker.txtChecker(txtcode) ;
allIsOK = checker.txtChecker(txtdavar) || allIsOK; 
allIsOK = checker.txtChecker(txtKomakHazine) || allIsOK;
// etc etc
```

Comment: thanks for complete answer. in comments i found that if use binary or (|) all of them will execute.

Comment: It's customary on StackOverflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) to "accept" the answer you find most helpful (look for the green tick) and to upvote any/every answer you find helpful.

Comment: Would be +1 if variable is not called `allIsOK` because your suggestion (as well as OP's code) computes "is any check passed" which for me does not reads "all is ok".

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Actually, his returns are inverted too, so it's "is any check failed".

Answer (score 1):

do

```
allIsOK = allIsOK && checker.txtChecker(txtdavar); //not||
```